# Bouncy Castle (Codename One lib) and AES-256 encryption

Tags: codenameone, bouncycastle

I tried searching for the documentation of the Codename One Bouncy Caste library API, but the "Wiki" section won't open:

https://code.google.com/p/bouncy-castle-codenameone-lib/

I don't know where the API is documented, however I need a specific information: I need to write a desktop application capable of encrypting and decrypting files taken from FileSystemStorage with AES-256. Maximum level security is a requirement, I don't know if security in this use case depends only on password strength or also on other parameters.

Comment: So, my question is where the API is documented and which API I need for the given purpose

Comment: If possible, I also would like a minimal code example for encrypting and decrypting a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the up to date repository: https://github.com/codenameone/bouncy-castle-codenameone-lib/

You can look at this for a sample of AES encryption: https://github.com/codenameone/bouncy-castle-codenameone-lib/blob/master/src/com/codename1/crypto/EncryptedStorage.java

Although I'm not sure about the key length.